# shortest path algorithm without loading graph in memory

Tags: networkx, shortest-path

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.all_shortest_paths.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.all_shortest_paths

I need to find all shortest paths given the source and target nodes.

`networkx` has a function to compute all shortest paths. But it requires the construction of the whole graph first.

In many cases, the shortest paths can be simple. For example, if the input is a TSV with each edge in a row, and the target node and the source node already has an edge between them, there is no need to construction such a graph in networkx first.

Is there an efficient algorithm to find all shortest paths so that the graph is constructed only when it is needed?

EDIT:

For start `a` and end `d`.

Input:

```
a   a
a   b
b   c
c   d
b   1
1   d
```

Output:

```
a   b   1   d
a   b   c   d
```

Comment: Could you post a small snippet of your data please,

Comment: Done. See the update.